# remove percentage sign from scale::percent() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage, floating-accuracy

This is my code.

```
my_boxplot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cyl,color=cyl)) + xlab('Cylinders') + ylab('Miles per Gallon %')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 0.01))
my_boxplot
```

This code shows the y-axis as percentages and I want to keep the accuracy to 2 decimal places and remove the percentage sign.

I tried this too. It only removes the percentage sign but does not set the accuracy.

`scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) paste0(x*100))`
Does anybody know how to keep the accuracy to desired decimal places and remove percentage sign from percentage values? Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have edited the code. sorry, it was not loaded right. this is for the R mtcars dataset and if you copy this to r console. It should work.

Comment: Why is the variable `mpg` labelled "Miles per gallon %"? Surely `mpg` is "mpg"? Do you need to change the y variable to be one that is a percentage?

Comment: Yes, peter1 I want to change the y axis to percentage value and as I am including percentage mark on the y-axis label I do not want it on every tick label. I want to keep the accuracy of every tick label to ceratin decimal places.

Comment: Thank you @MarBlo, could you please explain to me what str_extract(l,'[ 0-9.]+') do?

Comment: I am really new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
my_boxplot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cyl,color=cyl)) + xlab('Cylinders') + ylab('Miles per Gallon %')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, digits=2, nsmall=2))
my_boxplot
```

[image]

Comment: Yay, this works. Thank you so much. I slightly change your code to make x to x*100. It works perfectly. Thanks